# Common LISP - How to return statement

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, metaprogramming

I'm currently trying to learn how to program in "Common Lisp". Therefore, I'm currently dealing with a minor problem regarding the definition of macros. Said macro should work as follows: It takes a list of numbers, creates a temporary (initially empty) list which is populated with the squared numbers and returns it. Unfortunately, I have some problems with this source code.

```lisp
    (defmacro square_loop (args)
        (let ((res ()))
            (loop for x in args
                do (push (* x x) res))
            res
        )
    )
```

Regarding error messages, I think that the error is that I don't return a list but a function call which has the same content as the list. However, it would be evaluated as a function call which is not correct. Is there any way how I can write the macro correctly?

**EDIT**
I know that I could *technically* solve this problem with utilizing functions like *mapcar*. However, I wanted to see if my idead of a macro was even possible.

Comment: This is *not* what macros are for.  If you want a function, use a function.  A macro is something which transforms *source code* into other *source code*, and is used for extending the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't understand what macros are and what's their use case. I suggest you to read materials like

[7. Macros: Standard Control Constructs](https://gigamonkeys.com/book/macros-standard-control-constructs.html)

[8. Macros: Defining Your Own](https://gigamonkeys.com/book/macros-defining-your-own.html)

[2.4.6 Backquote](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/CLHS/Body/02_df.htm) + comma (operators used in my solution)

Usually, you use macros for transformations of source code or situations, when you want to control when (and if ever) something evaluates. You should avoid macros if your problem can be solved with a function. And I don't see any reason to use a macro for squaring every number in the list.

But just for learning purposes...

```
(defmacro square-loop (args)
  (let ((res '()))
    (loop for x in args
          do (push (* x x) res))
    `',res))

> (square-loop (1 2 3))
(9 4 1)
```

Notice three things:

- kebab-case (*square_loop* -> *square-loop*)
- proper formatting of parentheses
- `push` pushes every element in the front of the list, so the final result is actually reversed- I'm not sure whether you want it, so here is a similar solution without reversing:

```
(defmacro square-loop (args)
  `',(mapcar (lambda (x) (* x x)) args))

> (square-loop (1 2 3))
(1 4 9)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. A short follow-up question: So, if macros are used to extend the language, defining a DSL would be an appropriate situation where I could use macros, right?

Comment: @IlikedCPlusPlus: yes, that is what macros are for: seamlessly extending the language you have into the language you want.

Answer (score 3):

```
CL-USER 1 > (defmacro square_loop (args)
              (let ((res ()))
                (loop for x in args
                      do (push (* x x) res))
                res))
SQUARE_LOOP

CL-USER 2 > (square_loop (list 1 2 3))

Error: In * of (LIST LIST) arguments should be of type NUMBER.
  1 (continue) Return a value to use.
  2 Supply new arguments to use.
  3 (abort) Return to top loop level 0.

Type :b for backtrace or :c <option number> to proceed.
Type :bug-form "<subject>" for a bug report template or :? for other options.

CL-USER 3 : 1 >
```

Your main misunderstanding is what macros are supposed to do: they take code and generate new code. Your macro does not generate any code. It computes a result during macro expansion time.

So there is one case where it looks like it could do something useful:

```
CL-USER 6 > (square_loop (1 2 3 4))

Error: Illegal car 16 in compound form (16 9 4 1).
  1 (continue) Evaluate 16 and ignore the rest.
  2 (abort) Return to top loop level 0.

Type :b for backtrace or :c <option number> to proceed.
Type :bug-form "<subject>" for a bug report template or :? for other options.

CL-USER 7 : 1 >
```

So even this does not work, since the macro returns `(16 9 4 1)` as its result -> as code! But `(16 9 4 1)` is not valid Lisp code. Remember, valid Lisp code expects an operator (a function, macro, special form or a lambda expression) as the first element of the Lisp form. But `16` is not a valid operator, it is a number:

```
CL-USER 8 > (16 9 4 1)

Error: Illegal car 16 in compound form (16 9 4 1).
  1 (continue) Evaluate 16 and ignore the rest.
  2 (abort) Return to top loop level 0.

Type :b for backtrace or :c <option number> to proceed.
Type :bug-form "<subject>" for a bug report template or :? for other options.

CL-USER 9 : 1 >
```

If you want to return data, you would need to **quote it**:

```
'(16 9 4 1)
```

We can modify the macro:

```
CL-USER 10 > (defmacro square_loop (args)
              (let ((res ()))
                (loop for x in args
                      do (push (* x x) res))
                (list 'quote res)))
SQUARE_LOOP

CL-USER 11 > (square_loop (1 2 3 4))
(16 9 4 1)
```

Above takes a literal list and produces as a new form: `(quote (16 9 4 1))`. This quoted expression then gets evaluated to `(16 9 4 1)`.

Still: `(square_loop (list 1 2 3 4))` won't work...

And:

```
(let ((list '(1 2 3 4)))
  (square_loop list))
```

Above won't work either. Why? That would be for you to find out...